# Android: SetImageResource and OnDraw

Tags: android, image, imageview, ondraw

I know I can setImageResource in ImageView to set the image and onDraw can do any custom draw operation there. Will anything you draw within onDraw function override the image set in SetImageResource. I mean if I draw something as transparent, will it make the image set by the SetImageResource of that section to be transparent as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not. You can test it youself by making a View that extends ImageView

```
public class TestView extends ImageView {

    public TestView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //if you call super.onDraw first, then whatever you draw below will be on top of your image
        canvas.drawARGB(122, 122, 122, 122);
    }
}
```